# Unable to launch exe from another directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying to reboot a program after 20hours of execution, but I'm unable to launch it from another place than the current directory.

For example if I call:

```
my @arglist = ('..\Server\taktpreviewserver\TaktPlayer2.exe', 'VLC_Player');

exec(@arglist) or die "Unable to relaunch TaktPlayer2.exe";
```

That will work, but I need to acces to some stuff on `..\Server\taktpreviewserver\` .

So I did :

```
chdir('..\Server\taktpreviewserver');

my @arglist = ('TaktPlayer2.exe', 'VLC_Player');

exec(@arglist) or die "Unable to relaunch TaktPlayer2.exe";
```

That won't work if launched from the phpServer ... (but works fine if called separately !!)

Is there anything to know about `chdir` or launching program from a server ?

Ps : i'm on windows XP

Comment: Those do not look like php variables...

Comment: Right because it's perl.
I tagged php because there is no phpserver tag.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the PHP tag?

Comment: @Kurt there is **no such thing** as a php server....

Comment: It's exist but i thought it was a well known thing http://www.php-web-server.net/index.php, my bad

Comment: Check the chdir also: chdir('..\Server\taktpreviewserver') or die "Unable to chdir: $!";

Answer (score 1):

If this is run through a web application, your path may have been set to not include the current directory `.` (possible security concern), in which case your first solution with full path would work, but the second solution would not.

Possible fix would be to change `'TaktPlayer2.exe'` to `'./TaktPlayer2.exe'`, or provide the full path.

Comment: I've tried 
D:\TAKT_Engine\Server\taktpreviewserver
and adding D:\TAKT_Engine\Server\taktpreviewserver to the path
But infortunatly that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Kurt Try using it directly in the `exec`: `D:/TAKT_Engine/Server/taktpreviewserver/TaktPlayer2.exe`. Note that you can use `/` instead of backslash.

Comment: Yeah that work but I've the same problem, the current directory didn't change and the program can't access to file that should be in his current directory (D:/TAKT_Engine/Server/taktpreviewserver/).
Nota :
If i'm trying to chdir just before calling exec, the program never appear even if the exec is called with an absolute path
Problem seems to be coming from the chdir.

Comment: @Kurt I'm not sure what you are doing, and what you are trying to do. Either it works, or you still have a problem. It can't be both.

Comment: Ok, in fact i want to launch a program from a different current directory , and the last try didn't change anything. By the way i'm investigating on use Forks::Super .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user the calling-script is running as, the calling-script may not have permissions to execute the file you are trying to execute. Make sure you have permissions set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
# ...
my $path = "$Bin/../yadda/yadda";
chdir $path or die "Cannot chdir to $path: $!";
# ...
exec(@arglist) 
    or die "Unable to relaunch TaktPlayer2.exe (@arglist): $!";
```

$FindBin::Bin is always the directory your script is located in. See [perldoc FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/FindBin.pm).

Also note I include the system call arguments and `$!` into the `die()`/`croak()` message. It turns out to save time.

Comment: I tried it but the problem persists when i try to launch it from the server :(. In fact it seems to be more a server handling problem than a Perl one.

Comment: The problem is that there is none, nothing happens

Comment: I don't like the "nothing happens" error. I put a `die "HERE I AM";` in the beginning of the script and look into webserver's log in such cases. Or you can put a `warn "exec: @arglist";` right before the exec.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i decided to change the access to resources in the .exe in order to be able to make it work in another directory.